# Do all fasteners for a sliding door need to be in framing?

Tags: doors, studs

Just purchased a new townhome and for some reason the builder didn't think we needed a door between the master bedroom and bathroom (there is a door for the toilet).

We purchased a sliding barn door to fill in the doorway but there are some issues.  The rail for the door is 6 1/2 feet long with 5 pre drilled holed for attaching. The problem is when lining up the rail, either all 5 attachment goes into a stud but the door doesn't close all the way or I can get 2 attachments into a stud and 1 into 2x4 header but the 2 attachments left of the doorway will be in the drywall.

Will the 3 and 2 be strong enough?  Is it possible to get a longer railing?  Or should I drill a new hole into the rail and have 4 attachments into wood?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post some pictures of the railing?   I might take a chance using drywall if one hole was in the centre of the railing, but I would prefer all screws in solid wood, studs or using a piece of wood screwed into the studs that I can hang/screw the railing on.  I am assuming you brought the house already built so the missing door is a design statement instead of a mistake/building error.

Answer (score 4):

I would consider drilling extra holes to get screws into studs. Otherwise, you may have to bury "stretcher" wood between studs behind the drywall to allow for the factory holes to be used.

Comment: Yes, you risk sag (which can be _horizontal_) without fasteners at adequately close intervals.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question...

I just noticed this barn door kit comes with dry wall anchors so I guess they think they drywall can hold the door with anchors.  I will be doing 3 bolts in wood and 2 in drywall with anchors.

Comment: Good idea, wall anchors wont be enough.